# How to make the async function in useEffect excute in order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The code below console 1,2,4,5,3,6. How to let it console 1,2,3,4,5,6?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-4bul5

```
const Foo = () => {
  const sleep = (timer) => {
    return new Promise((res) => {
      setTimeout(res, timer)
    })
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1)
    const foo = async () => {
      console.log(2)
      await sleep(1000);
      console.log(3)
    }
    foo();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(4)
    const foo = async () => {
      console.log(5)
      await sleep(1000);
      console.log(6)
    }
    foo();
  }, []);

  return <div>111</div>
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't affect the order in which ``useEffect`` is called. In your case I recommend a single ``useEffect`` call.

Comment: I would also recommend a single useEffect, you can pass to useEffect the result of `useCallback((async () => ...)(), [...])` , that way you can use `await/async`. Use a `state` toggle to run the effect.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you @Tracer69

Answer (score -1):

If you make Foo an `async` function, then you can use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) on promises to do them synchronously.